# I couldn't get past this error in open cv while using it in spider?

Tags: python, deep-learning, anaconda, opencv

[error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-h4wtvo23\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.cpp:1689: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmKPY.jpg)

Comment: Please revise so that readers can see the code that threw the error _and_ any solutions you attempted.

Answer (score 0):

please read the error message carefully and thoroughly. it says something is `empty()` when it shouldn't be ("Assertion failed") and it gives you the source file and line number within OpenCV. you can find that file and look into it.

the assertion is thrown here: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/objdetect/src/cascadedetect.cpp#L1689

primary problem:

- check if face_cascade.empty() or eye_cascade.empty() after creating the objects in your code. if any of them is empty, it failed to load the xml file. check that the xml files are in an accessible place.

also:

- check that video_capture.isOpened() is True, or else you can't read the video
- say `rv, frame = video_capture.read()`
- check that rv is True, or else break the loop